# how to do this complex fetch in 1 query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an application with tutors and courses and subscribers and ratings. These are the tables I am using:

```
tbl_tutors:
    id
    name

tbl_subscribers:
    id
    user_id
    course_id

tbl_courses:
    id
    name
    tutor_id

tbl_ratings:
    id
    user_id
    course_id
    rating
```

I need to get 1 tutor with the number of courses he has, the number of total subscribers for those courses and the average course rating for all his courses. This is a lot of data; can it be done in 1 sql query or do I need to code foreach statements in php to get the average ratings and the total subscribers for those courses?

Comment: why prefix everything with `tbl` - what is the point?

Comment: Where's the `tbl_teachers: id tutor_id course_id`? Is that inside `tbl_subscribers`?

Comment: Joins typically take longer to perform than multiple `SELECT` queries, particularly with a lot of data, but I suppose they're technically more elegant. If you're expecting to do a lot of maintenance on this system, the multiple `foreach()` calls might make reading the code easier, and the system would be more resilient against changes to the DB fields.

Comment: There is no table relating tutors with the courses?

Comment: @Naltharial you beat me to it :)

Comment: where's the FK for tutor id in courses? Is there a joining table?

Comment: What is the relation between tble_tutors and tbl_courses? If it is M-N relation, you probably have another table, right?

Comment: @Mythriel FK means foreign key

Comment: you need to add tutor_id in tbl_courses to link them

Comment: @JamieDexter well, lets not jump the gun on `JOIN`s here. :) The overhead of multiple queries combined with the lack of ref and eq_ref index optimizations for `JOIN`s might well slow down multiple `SELECT`s considerably. *Especially* on large datasets that could benefit from indexes.

Comment: there is a tutor_id in tbl_courses, sry i forgot to add it

Comment: i will have a page where i list all the authors, with all their data, i am not sure if making multiple selects would be a good choice

Comment: @Naltharial: `lack of ref and eq_ref index optimizations for JOINs` that sounds like it might have been the cause of a problem I had that was scarily solved by switching a join to a dependent subquery (>.<). Can you point me to any resources on this? Ta

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I find that the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization.html) on the subject is usually a good starting point. `Understanding the Query Execution Plan` in particular can shed light on why exactly `JOIN`s are (/can be) beneficial to speed.

Comment: @Naltharial: I am familiar with the docs and was hoping you had a more specific item to point me at. Not to worry!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit sorry if it seemed condescending, it's just that there isn't all that much more to say on the topic. If you've gone through, more specifically, the part on [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html) which can tell you when MySQL can use indexes for `ref` and `eq_ref`, then it's just a matter of correctly applying them. [HackMySQL](http://hackmysql.com/case4) has an article on indexing for `JOIN`s as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.name "Tutor", count(c.id) "# courses", count(s.id) "# subscribers"
from tbl_tutors t, tbl_subscribers s, tbl_courses c, tbl_ratings r
where t.id = XXX
and c.tutor_id = t.id 
and s.course_id = c.id
and r.user_id = s.user_id
group by t.name
```

this sql will get you all you need besides the courses average (substitute the XXX with the tutor-id you want to find). for courses average you can run a separate select.

Comment: not working, i get strange results..... i need all tutors, and for every tutor to get the number of all his courses, the number of all the subscribers for those courses and the total votes for the courses and avg rating

Comment: add the "group by" line. sorry I can't test it - check the result and if there's an error - post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Well do you need totals per tutor-course combination or a total (and average) at the tutor level?

And what is the rating table adding over the subscriber table? Aren't they both unique user-course combinations?

If one user attends multiple courses by the same tutor, how many subscribers do they count as?

The SQL provided by @alfasin is easily extended to all tutors. The syntax below is for SQL server, you may need to change for MySQL

```
Select t.name, count(distinct c.id) courseCount, count(s.id) subscribers, avg(r.rating) subRating  
From tbl_tutors t  
Inner join tbl_courses c on c.tutorid = t.id  
Inner join tbl_subscribers s on s.courseid = c.id  
Inner join tbl_ratings r on r.userid = s.userid and r.courseid = c.id  
Group by t.name
```

Note that when trying to build queries like this it's usually best to do them **without** grouping so you can inspect which rows are contributing to the counts and ensure you're including everything you expect and that you're not duplicating results